# SQL Server Data Transit

Tags: security, sql-server, rds

Random question came up today and I wasnt sure of the best way to answer.

If we have an RDS Instance in AWS that is running Microsoft SQL Server and we open up remote access to a Web-App hosted internally (Obviously firewalled and IP restricted). When the data is 'in transit' is it encrypted?

Comment: Not unless you setup SSL, Column Level Encryption, or depending on version, Always Encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely not.

The simplest way to see basic connection encryption is to run

SELECT encrypt_option, * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections

See [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) for reference

Beyond that, yes, Always Encrypted would do so.

The advanced way is to run [Microsoft Message analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) and simply see if the traffic on querying cleartext data is cleartext or not.  On basic connection encryption, you can also look for the handshake (Hello messages) and see what cipher suite was negotiated.